# Django Models: error when using DateField as ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-key-relationship, datefield

Having an issue when trying to use DateField of a model class as the ForeignKey for another model class, and using default set to today on both classes. The error message is:

> django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'self.date' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."]

code:

```
class DailyImage(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 1000)
    image = models.CharField(max_length = 1000)
    location = models.CharField(max_length = 1000)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id) + ": " + self.name + ", " + self.location

class JournalEntry(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    journal = models.CharField(max_length = 5000)
    image = models.ForeignKey(DailyImage, to_field='date', default='self.date')
```

The site is a daily journal. Each day, it adds an image from unsplash.it to the DailyImage class, which is then displayed as the header on the home page, and header on the page for the journal entry created that day. When a journal entry is created, it should automatically be referenced to the image that was created that day.

testing it in shell, the date fields seem to match, but are formatted as: datetime.date(YYYY, MM, DD)

```
>>> a = JournalEntry.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> a
<JournalEntry: test>
>>> a.date
datetime.date(2016, 11, 7)
>>> from journal.models import DailyImage as image
>>> b = image.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> b.date
datetime.date(2016, 11, 7)
>>> b.date == a.date
True
```

Any suggestions to how this should be done properly would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

a.date returns the datetime object, but you have to set the format.

```
t = datetime.date(2016, 11, 7) 
t.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
# '2016-11-07'
```

You could also set the default datetime format in settings.py

```
DATETIME_FORMAT = 'Y-m-d'
```

However I'm not sure that would be a solution in your situation.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. none of these seemed to work for me though. instead, I created a new variable today = datetime.today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") and assigned it to the image field:

>image = models.ForeignKey(DailyImage, to_field='date', default='today')

haven't tested it yet to see if it's working properly, but so far it looks ok

Comment: I think you should have just left out `to_field='date'` (and the default), and it will be automatically linked by the `id`. What you are doing is very uncommon. Then you can also leave out the Date for the Image, since it is already available through the Journal.

Comment: And while at it, why not use a OneToOneField instead of Foreignkey (=one to many).

Comment: Thanks Ixer! I actually wanted to link it to date since there will be a new image every day (which will also be displayed on the home page splash), but not all users will create a new entry that day. I'd like to tie the entry to the image from the day it was created. I'd also like the images to be global and entries to be user specific. I'd definitely like to make this cleaner, and would love any other suggestions